# No internet connection after using wifiphisher kali linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I have downloaded Wifiphisher from github and try some new stuff.

After I close the program I have no internet connection. I tried with wired connection and still don't have a connection. Restarting the network-manager and nothing.

I have second wifi adapter TP-LINK TLWN722N. When I plugin the second adapter the light doesn't not flashing. When I enabled monitoring mode the light is flashing, and when I stop it the light dies down.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The wifiphisher puts the WiFi in monitor mode and hence you lose your internet connection. To restart your internet connection, use the following code

```
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo service networking restart
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Check now in ifconfig if your wlan is up and monitor mode is down.